# How do I install Gimp 2.8 in Windows without administrative permissions?

Tags: gimp, windows

I want my creativity to flow right now but I don't have access to the administrator account.

Comment: Maybe this should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It can't be on stack overflow because it's not a programming issue. I thought it would be better on here or on superuser.

Comment: Probably Super User. But at least you got your answer here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try using a portable version: http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable

It runs from a folder rather than actually installing so you shouldn't need admin privileges.